# How to create a HTTPS login form easily?

Tags: php, ssl, https

I'm new to web programming. I've created a simple login form (with php). Now I want to turn this one into a HTTPS (with SSL) login form. What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: Type https in your browser, lol. Your question is not clear, to me at least.

Comment: First of all, HTTPS should be enabled on the server and to do so yo need to install a certificate (either a self-signed one or a certificate bought from a certificate authority). Then, have your link point to the log-in page via https scheme

Comment: From a programming perspective, there is no difference whatsoever. SSL is a **transparent** transport protocol. Your server (eg: Apache, IIS) should handle that for you.

Comment: Generally you'll need to enable ssl modules on your web server, use a certificate (either a self-signed certificate or buy one from CA vendors) and optionally define routes to redirect http to https.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to [enable SSL](https://web.archive.org/web/20180320002149/http://www.onlamp.com/2008/03/04/step-by-step-configuring-ssl-under-apache.html), if it is not already enabled
If you are going to run this in production, you will also need to purchase and
install an SSL cert instead of a self-signed cert.

If SSL is enabled, then running your form with https instead of http as the comment above says will work

To force users to use the SSL version add something like the following to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritebase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login\.php https://yourdomain.com/login.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I don't need to change anything, setup SSL and just use the login form with https://? Or should I move my login page to a special folder? Also what stops users from changing https to http and use unsecured login page? Can I disable it?

Comment: you could use htaccess to rewrite any requests to your login form to https://yourdomain.com/your-login-form

Answer (score 5):

Get an SSL certificate.  Once you have HTTPS working on your server (work with your hosting company to get it working), you can use code similar to the following to force an HTTPS connection in PHP.  .htaccess is another option, mentioned elsewhere.

```
<?

function current_protocol()
{
    $protocol = 'http';

    if ( array_key_exists( 'HTTPS', $_SERVER ) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' )
    {
        $protocol = 'https';
    }

    return $protocol;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
function current_has_ssl()
{
    return current_protocol() == 'https';
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
function force_https()
{
    if ( current_has_ssl() == false )
    {
        header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
        header( 'Location: https://example.com' );
        exit();
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Usage:

force_https(); // at the top of a script before any output.
```