# How to migrate my http php pages to https pages

Tags: php, ssl, https

My php site is hosted on a host which is also hosting many other websites. I'm sure that the host has the ssl certificate. There are some http login and register pages on my site. Now I need to migrate them to https. I've googled a lot and found this:
[How to create a HTTPS login form easily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481658/how-to-create-a-https-login-form-easily)

But I still have two questions:
1. Do I have to purchase another certificate or I can somehow use my host's certificate?
2. After SSL is enabled and the certificate is installed, I'll just add the following lines to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritebase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login\.php https://yourdomain.com/login.php [L,R=301]
```

After that, the https connection would work, it that right? But would https connection be applied to all of my pages or just the login pages? Since I don't want to apply https to pages other than login pages. Also, where should I place .htaccess. I have multiple .htaccess files in different directory.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: you need a cert with **YOUR** domain name in it. you can't just slap up any random cert and expect it to work. e.g. a cert for "foo.com" will not work properly on "bar.com".

Comment: Adding to what @MarcB said: Even if you could, that would defeat the purpose...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So after the certificate is installed, if I add above lines to .htaccess, would https connection be applied to all of my pages or just login pages? I just want it to be applied to login pages.